# How do I use a background thread to shut down (on detecting a key press) a main thread running a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to automate the following: open calculator, close it by clicking on the red x. To stop this script, I want it to detect when the escape key is pressed, and then stop the script execution.

I've tried using two threads, but the information was not passed between them correctly, and both threads were running until they finished. I then tried moving the opening of calculator and closing it to main, and kept the escape press detection thread in the background. Now, my script only opens calculator once, and doesn't open it again.

```py
import threading
from pynput import keyboard

global windowOpened
windowOpened = False

def on_press(key):
    pass

def on_release(key):
    if str(key) == 'Key.esc':
        print('Exiting')
        return False

def sleeper():
    global escapePressed
    escapePressed = False
    with keyboard.Listener(
    on_press = on_press,
    on_release = on_release) as listener:
        escapePressed = True
        listener.join()

t1 = threading.Thread(target = sleeper, name = 'esc_detection_thread')
t1.start()

for i in range(10):
    if escapePressed == True:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        #open calculator and close it by clicking the red x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `os._exit` method to exit the entire process:

```
import os

def on_release(key):
    if str(key) == 'Key.esc':
        print('Exiting')
        os._exit(0)
```

Comment: This definitely works. If I were to turn the open calc and click to exit into a thread that was executing along with the detection thread, is there a way to shut down just the calculator thread? I found a need to change the calculator open loop into a thread that continuously executes. Thanks!